# How to add border radius for custom Rectangular (by clipRectByRect ) in echarts?

Tags: echarts

Im trying to draw a gantt figure by the function below, but seems like the official documentations and examples didn't give the way to add border radius to those kind of rect, is there anyone know how to deal with it ?

```
function renderItem(params, api) {
var categoryIndex = api.value(0);
var start = api.coord([api.value(1), categoryIndex]);
var end = api.coord([api.value(2), categoryIndex]);
var height = api.size([0, 1])[1] * 0.6;

var rectShape = echarts.graphic.clipRectByRect({
    x: start[0],
    y: start[1] - height / 2,
    width: end[0] - start[0],
    height: height
}, {
    x: params.coordSys.x,
    y: params.coordSys.y,
    width: params.coordSys.width,
    height: params.coordSys.height
});

return rectShape && {
    type: 'rect',
    transition: ['shape'],
    shape: rectShape,
    style: api.style()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

They do provide an approach for custom shape to add border radius, it can be find in the documentation. it is `shape{ r: 10}`